# How to export bigger images from TimeManager?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

Whilst I think 'TimeManager' works very well, is it possible to define the output scale, so that the output provides better quality data when exporting?

There are no options in its interface where I can define the output scale and size, it´s only possible to select the folder for exporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Time Manager always exports the current map canvas.

Support for custom output size will probably depend on [Print Composer](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/138) integration, which is currently an open feature request. The plan is to look into it for future versions built on QGIS 3.